# XML File Transformations for inner text of an element?

Tags: asp.net, xslt, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, web.config-transform

I am in the process of setting up a release pipeline for one of our solutions, but I am struggling to use file transformations on my web.config to alter inner text values of elements.

From what it looks like, you can replace/insert/etc values attached to specific attributes, but not the inner text. Does this mean I will not be able to use file transformations for my purposes?

```
<setting name="Test" serializeAs="String">
<value>True</value>
</setting>
```

That "True" value must be replaced with False. There are quite a number of similar instances that need to be replaced. Can this be done with XML file transformations? I cannot use the variable substitution method as it only applies to certain elements like connectionString, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple XSL transformation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="setting[@name='Test']/value">
    <xsl:element name="value">False</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknsB

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Seems really simple, I just wasn't familiar with how transformations worked, in addition to the syntax.